# ShellExecuteW not working well on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8.1, shellexecute

I call standard `ShellExecuteW` call on Windows8.1 to open PPS (powerpoint slide) file.

This works just fine on Windows 7. On Windows 8.1. it reports "There is no program associated to open the file". Of course, the file association is set and if file is saved and run from Explorer (double clicked) it opens just fine. I also tried to change association and to associate another program and then associate back to PPS viewer, no improvement. It just doesn't work for W8.1 but the same call works on earlier Windows.

Can anyone give me a clue what might be wrong here?

The code used to open file is very simple and I see no errors with it:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\path\\to\\file.pps", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

// Check if result is error
if ((int)hinst <= 32)
    {
    wchar_t buf[512] = { 0 };
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 512, NULL);

    MSGBOX(buf);
    }
```

I use free PPS viewer as found here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13

I found [something similar](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/073d02a6-1181-4694-9e50-d6a05bd80663/shellexecutew-w-symlinks-broken-on-windows-81?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) which points to that this could be a bug in Win8.1. Can anyone confirm this? Or reveal a workaround?

Comment: Your error handling is broken, ShellExecute() doesn't report errors through GetLastError().  So you don't *really* know why it doesn't work.  Do move to ShellExecuteEx(), keep in mind that running on a 64-bit OS might have something to do with it, be sure to call CoInitializeEx(), use SysInternals Process Monitor to get insight.

Comment: How come that `SE_ERR_NOASSOC` corresponds to the error message which is shown in the message box if it doesn't use `GetLastError()`? I will attempt to use `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: @Coder12345 Read the documentation if you want to know how error handling is to be done. Making it up is never a great idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

The problem on W8.1 was that the verb `open` was not registered to the application so it used different default verb. So if the `ShellExecute` call is replaced with:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, L"C:\\path\\to\\file.pps", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Then the system looks for a default verb which may or may not be `open` (usually is), so by not using this verb explicitly it leaves this decision to the system.

Comment: Yup, and this behavior is documented in the [`ShellExecute()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx): "NULL - The default verb is used, if available. If not, the `open` verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry."

Comment: Looks like you only gave SO 1 hour to answer your question. Was that intentional?

Comment: I found the answer and shared it with everyone since nobody else answered, just like I do every time I found the answer before others do. Not the first question I self-answered and some have been online for days. I can't really go into guessing mode to know when someone is going to answer. If you feel this as injustice and not my desire to help the community, feel free to answer yourself and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @david.pfx: answering your own question is not only permitted, it is encouraged.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Of course, but it is generally courteous to allow a question to run for a little while first. You never know, there might be someone out there on a different timezone with a much better answer. I think 24 hours is reasonable as a policy. An hour is too short.

Comment: @david.pfx please pardon me, I do not have time to participate in this debate. I needed solution fast, I found it fast, I answered fast to help others. If you feel it as injustice, make your own answer and I'll check it so you can get some points. What I do know is that debates in the comments are not encouraged. So let's end it here and move on.

Comment: @david.pfx: I've posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225783/whats-the-current-consensus-on-answering-your-own-question to serve as a more appropriate place for discussion and to get advice from the community.